# How to upgrade from Debian 9 to Debian 10 with Qubes OS?

Tags: debian, qubes-os

I have Debian 9 on Qubes OS, but I want to upgrade it to 10. I want to upgrade from 9 because 10 became a stabilizer, but I do not know how. https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/template/debian/upgrade-8-to-9/ I used this as a reference but I do not know. How do you do it?

Comment: This is _not a programming question_. This is not on-topic here. You should ask elsewhere. It might be on-topic at [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming as outlined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

you could install a fresh debian 10 by using by running 
`sudo qubes-dom0-update qubes-template-debian-10`

from dom0

Answer (score -1):

The guide that you refer to is for Debian 8 (jessie) to Debian 9 (stretch).

You want to upgrade from 9 (stretch) to 10 (buster).

So the summary in the guide should change to:

```
    [user@dom0 ~]$ qvm-clone debian-9 debian-10
    [user@dom0 ~]$ qvm-run -a debian-10 gnome-terminal
    [user@debian-10 ~]$ sudo sed -i 's/stretch/buster/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
    [user@debian-10 ~]$ sudo sed -i 's/stretch/buster/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qubes-r3.list
    [user@debian-10 ~]$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
    [user@debian-10 ~]$ sudo apt-get autoremove

(Shut down TemplateVM by any normal means.)

    [user@dom0 ~]$ qvm-trim-template debian-10

(Done.)
```

Comment: Yes it did. However, I checked the version after that, but it was 9.